# How can I connect to the same server in Agar.io?

Tags: networking, agar.io

1. Choose any server [image: Choose any server]
2. Right click - Inspect element (or press f12)
3. Click console [image: Click console]
4. From console copy the websocket ip -> 'ws://x.x.x.x/x'
5. write connect("ws://x.x.x.x/x") example: connect('ws://123.122.199.84:43')

These steps will allow to connect to a specific server. This way you can play with your friends in the same server.

My question is is there a way to open a web socket via url bar? For example is there a way to write something like http://ws://123.122.199.84.agar.io:43/ for directly connecting to a server?

Comment: hey. Please don't attach any answers to your question. Answer your own question yourself instead, using the answer function. after that, you can accept it. This way, you'll get some upvotes because your post is actually very useful

Comment: My question is different than how you understand then. I want an easy solution. I gave the bad solution. It is not possible to do without giving the bad solution.

Comment: You block ads? Everyone knows cells who block ads die quicker.

Comment: This question is older, but I believe the answers on the other question are more up to date.  Therefore, this should be closed as a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE: There is an other way**

I was just reminded of another way to connect to an custom Agar.io server. And it's so incredibly simple.

Navigate your browser to the normal Agar.io address, but add a query at the end of the url like so:

```
http://agar.io?[ip address here]
```

Please note that you should not enter the `ws://` prefix. Here is an example:

```
http://agar.io?127.0.0.1:443
```

And you do not prefer to do so, you may use the updated bookmarklet:

```
javascript: location.href = "http://agar.io?" + prompt("IP Address", "XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX"); void 0;
```

Another more user friendly bookmarklet created by [@E. Sundin](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/139799/e-sundin). It's a jumble of text, but it works:

```
javascript: if(window.location.host%20!%3D%3D%20%22agar.io%22)%20%7Bwindow.location%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fagar.io%2F%22%3B%7D%20else%20if(typeof%20_ws%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22undefined%22)%20%7Bvar%20server%20%3D%20prompt(%22Server%20url%22%2C%20localStorage.getItem(%22__server%22))%3Bconsole.log(%22Selected%3A%20%22%20%2B%20server)%3BlocalStorage.setItem(%22__server%22%2C%20server)%3Bwindow._ws%20%3D%20WebSocket%3Bwindow.WebSocket%20%3D%20function(a%2C%20b)%20%7Bvar%20_server%20%3D%20localStorage.getItem(%22__server%22)%20%7C%7C%20%22%22%3Bif(_server.length%20!%3D%3D%200)%20a%20%3D%20_server%3Bconsole.log(%22WebSocket%20opened%20with%3A%20%22%20%2B%20Array.prototype.join.call(arguments%2C%20%22%2C%22))%3Breturn%20arguments.length%20%3D%3D%3D%202%20%3F%20new%20_ws(a%2C%20b)%20%3A%20new%20_ws(a)%3B%7D%3B%7D%20void%200%3B
```

---

**EDIT: This no longer works**

This function was removed by the dev and this is now broken.
I will keep it here for reference.

The dev has also added a new game mode, `Party`. With that you can connect with your friends. At the moment it only works with FFA rules.

Of course if you want to play Any of the other modes, again you can connect to the server via the country selection as the **same time as your friend**.

---

**Broken stuff:**

> Actually, yes there is.
>
> Paste this into the address bar **while on the Agar.io website**:
>
> ```
> javascript: connect("ws://" + prompt("Server IP", "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXX")); void 0;
> ```
>
> Now most browsers will remove the `javascript:` from the start as a
>   security measure; you just need to go back there and add it.
>
> It will prompt you for the server IP. Please don't add `ws://` at the
>   start, include the whole IP with the port number.
>
> As well you can bookmarklet the JS code. You can easily bookmarklet
>   the code with my bookmarklet tool [located here](http://bit64.x10host.com/code/bookmarklet). For more on
>   bookmarklets, [see here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/bookmarklets-perform-common-web-page-tasks).
>
> ---
>
> I would also like to mention something else. When you connect to the
>   server on a specified port you will not always be on the same game.
>
> The second you connect to the port, the server selects a game with the
>   least amount of players from that port. If the all of the games from
>   that port is full, it will display an error and try a different
>   server.
>
> Connecting to a server this way is not reliable, especially if you
>   want to join the same game as your friends. **It might cause you some
>   grief.**
>
> The only way around this I can see is to connect to the **same
>   server** at the **same time** hoping that the server will select the
>   same game for you and your friend. Of course this is not always the
>   case.

Comment: Can it be that this doesn't work anymore? I get the message: `TypeError: b is undefined`.

Comment: @TrudleR I just tested this and it works in Internet Explorer, Chrome and Firefox. What browser are you using? And what IP address did you enter in the prompt?

Comment: I use firefox and tried that with my brother, we both had the same problem somehow. I then see only the agar background without anything to do there.

Comment: @TrudleR What IP did you type in the prompt dialog? You need to type the whole IP without the `ws://`.

Comment: Yeah I know that, I really did exactly what you said. The dialog also comes up. I also wrote the "javascript:" since this really got deleted by firefox if you copy&paste. The IP I typed in isn't a local IP address if you think that. It's an IP address with mostly the ports :443 oder :XXXX something with 4 digits, 1505 or similar. I may retry it this evening if you say that it should work. I didn't pay much attention to the "join at the same time" part. :)

Comment: @TrudleR I am sure that this works in the latest version of Firefox. Also here is an example IP address to insert into the prompt: `167.114.174.68:443` (US East).
If the above doesn't work, please try this modified code:
`javascript: connect("ws://" + prompt("Server IP", "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXX"), true); void 0;` And the "join at the same time" thing does not affect the code. Only once you are connected it affects the game that you join.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work anymore, it says undefined length

Comment: Sry, wasn't able to test it until now. Hope I find the time soon.

Comment: not working any more. Is there any other solution?

Comment: This might work for private servers but for other servers (only tested FFA) I wrote [this gist](https://gist.github.com/krokofant/b85b2c0723ebfafd69bd). One could make it a bookmark.

Comment: I created [this bookmark](https://gist.github.com/krokofant/9207c9795d498a5692ca) of the above gist. Could you include this in your answer?

Comment: @E.Sundin I updated the answer to include your bookmarklet. I encoded it to ensure that it would not have issues with the browser, but it still works the same.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/agario-server-browser/hongpdkjnjhijmdnogoicadboadgllhi?hl=en) for it.

You just type the IP address out in the Start GUI.

Comment: Maybe provide a link?

Comment: @Alagaros I think this is the link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/agario-server-browser/hongpdkjnjhijmdnogoicadboadgllhi?hl=en

Comment: @Thellimist add it to the answer instead of commenting :)

Answer (score 1):

Agar.io just started to support `http://agar.io/?XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:PORT` url.

Example: `http://agar.io/?37.187.163.130:1501`

The IP can be found the same way. Press f12 or right click - inspect element - console

[image]